# Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom(assemblyPath).GetName() VS Assembly.LoadFrom(assemblyPath).GetName()

Tags: c#, system.reflection

We have twice the same dlls in separate folders.

When we load the second dlls using

```
Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom(assemblyPath)
```

we get an error :

```
"API restriction: The assembly 'file.dll' has already loaded from a different location. It cannot be loaded from a new location within the same appdomain."
```

Which is understandable but when we do :

```
Assembly.LoadFrom(assemblyPath);
```

it works fine.

Why ? what whould change using the "ReflectionOnly" method.

In our case the only usage would be to use the GetName() method on the result, and I guess that in this case, the result should be strictly the same ?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/305835/c-sharp-assembly-load-vs-assembly-reflectiononlyload

Comment: @Amit just that a question mentions the same two method names does not mean it is a duplicate. The [question you link to](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/305835/c-sharp-assembly-load-vs-assembly-reflectiononlyload) asks about errors when using `ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you load an assembly for `ReflectionOnly`, only the metadata gets loaded. This allows you to inspect its types, but not instantiate or execute any of them.

There's also a [property indicating whether an assembly was loaded for reflection only](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.reflectiononly(v=vs.110).aspx).

So per AppDomain, an assembly can be loaded once: either fully, or for reflection only. Given it's already fully loaded, you can't load it again for reflection only.

The call to `Assembly.LoadFrom()`, even when provided two different paths, will only load the same assembly once, as long as they match in version. See also [Side effects of calling Assembly.Load multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9315716/side-effects-of-calling-assembly-load-multiple-times).

See also: [MSDN: How to: Load Assemblies into the Reflection-Only Context](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172331(v=vs.110).aspx).