# Cannot get types from assembly after ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom

Tags: c#, reflection

I have consulted code on the website http://codeproject.com with the title "Loading Assemblies from Anywhere into a New AppDomain" of Marius Bancila,  but I tested the error as in the attached picture, currently, I don't know resolve, hope you help, thank you.

Link Code
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/453778/Loading-Assemblies-from-Anywhere-into-a-New-AppDom#_articleTop

Test

```
public class Program
{
    [STAThread]
    public static void Main()
    {
        var project = @"D:\Github\BeyConsPlugin\BeyConsProject\bin\x64\Debug\BeyConsRevitProject.dll";//Path to assembly
        var manager = new AssemblyReflectionManager();
        var success = manager.LoadAssembly(project, Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
        if (success)
        {
            var result = manager.Reflect(project, (a) =>
            {
                return a.GetTypes();
            });
            Console.WriteLine(string.Join("\n", result.Select(x => x.Name)));
        }            
        Console.ReadKey();
        manager.UnloadAssembly(project);
    }       
}
```

Error
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Could not load file or assembly or one of its dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4469929/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-or-one-of-its-dependencies)

Answer (score 1):

### Assembly Resolver not Set

Marius's code has a bug in `AssemblyReflectionProxy` with regards that the Assembly Resolver is not set if you call `LoadAssembly` unlike `Reflect<>` which does.

Depending on how a child app domain is created, when loading assemblies it might only have access to the folder as specified during creation.  If you need to assembly probe elsewhere for the assembly or its dependencies you need a Assembly Resolver.  When .NET is looking for an assembly for a domain, it will call your handler as specified in the assemblie's `ReflectionOnlyAssemblyResolve` event.  If not specified or if the resolver fails to locate the assembly, it will bubble up and throw a load fail exception.

I suggest you change the code from:

```
public class AssemblyReflectionProxy : MarshalByRefObject
{
  private string _assemblyPath;

  public void LoadAssembly(String assemblyPath)
  {
     try
     {
        _assemblyPath = assemblyPath;
        Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom(assemblyPath);
     }
     catch (FileNotFoundException)
     {
        // Continue loading assemblies even if an assembly 
        // cannot be loaded in the new AppDomain.
     }
  }
```

...to:

```
public class AssemblyReflectionProxy : MarshalByRefObject
{
  private string _assemblyPath;

  public void LoadAssembly(String assemblyPath)
  {
     try
     {
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ReflectionOnlyAssemblyResolve // <---- add me
             += OnReflectionOnlyResolve; 

        _assemblyPath = assemblyPath;
        Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom(assemblyPath);
     }
     catch (FileNotFoundException)
     {
        // Continue loading assemblies even if an assembly 
        // cannot be loaded in the new AppDomain.
     }
  }
```

You can see this in Sacha's [original code](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42312/Loading-Assemblies-in-Separate-Directories-Into-a) that on which Marius based his.

### Add Provision for Resolve Paths

The other problem with the code is that both assume that when loading one assembly, any dependent assemblies are in the same folder something that may not always be the case.

Alter `AssemblyReflectionProxy` to include a list of paths in which to probe:

```
public List<string> ResolvePaths { get; set; }
```

Then modify OnReflectionOnlyResolve to resemble the following:

```
private Assembly OnReflectionOnlyResolve(ResolveEventArgs args, DirectoryInfo directory)
{
     Assembly loadedAssembly =
         AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ReflectionOnlyGetAssemblies()
             .FirstOrDefault(
               asm => string.Equals(asm.FullName, args.Name,
                   StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));

     if (loadedAssembly != null)
     {
        return loadedAssembly;
     }

    foreach (var tryFolder in ResolvePaths)
    {
        var asmName = args.Name.Split(',');
        var assemblyPath = Path.Combine(tryFolder, asmName[0] + ".dll");

        if (!File.Exists(assemblyPath))
            return null;

         return Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom(assemblyPath);
    }
}
```

### What's in a name?

Both articles neglected to point out the fine print when using `ReflectionOnlyLoad`. Though [Sacha did at least mention](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42312/Loading-Assemblies-in-Separate-Directories-Into-a) his code was for a *"code generator"* I can't help but wonder that both articles with their *"`Loading Assemblies`....into a New AppDomain"* are perhaps somewhat subject to interpretation.

The aim of `ReflectionOnlyLoad` is just that - for *reflection*.  If you load an assembly via this method you cannot execute any code in it.  Additionally and somewhat surprising at first to most assembly reflector programmers including me is that calling `GetCustomAttributes` will also [fail](https://stackoverflow.com/a/306654/585968) (because it attempts to *"instantiate"* types in the assembly).

If you are writng your own plug-in system in which each plug-in has its own App Domain, the `Assembly` reflection and load methods are useful for different stages of the plug-in system loading pipeline:

1. first pass - use `ReflectionOnlyLoad` as a way to *inspect* the plug-in to see if it is valid; perhaps you want to run some security checks safe in the knowledge that none of the plug-ins code can run during this phase
2. second pass - after verifying the plug-in, you can safely `Load`/`LoadFrom` the assembly and execute the code

Comment: I edited like you but still got the error. Don't mind can you edit for me, sorry, I'm not IT. Link code: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1877WMwGVbfw4fXceQuweaxy-hp4U5s10nM5BtUqtHqI/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @NhuTruong see _"Add Provision for Resolve Paths"_ update above

Comment: Sorry @MickyD, my problem still hasn't been resolved.

Comment: @NhuTruong please take note of _[Any answer that gets the asker going in the right direction is helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)_.  SO isn't meant to be a venue to fix _all the problems_ in _3rd party_ code.  Also be aware of _[When is “EDIT”/“UPDATE” appropriate in a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127639/when-is-edit-update-appropriate-in-a-post)_.   I quote _[posts need to be standalone, without any history. These sites are not forums,](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127639/when-is-edit-update-appropriate-in-a-post)_.

Comment: @NhuTruong I encourage you to first visit Sacha's code and modify it accordingly.  The other codebase is more complex and possibly problematic

Comment: I have removed the update according to forum regulations because the above part is still unsolved, thank you for helping me.

Comment: @NhuTruong _"...the above part is still unsolved"_.  I disagree.  Your question was about  the problem when calling `manager.LoadAssembly` which I have pointed out and showed you how to fix it

Comment: Do you have the final code for me to reference, the way you suggested it is still not resolved? I still don't understand.

Comment: @NhuTruong Yes its in the answer above